# Finding out the time a filesystem was last mounted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, ext4

I want to find out the last time a filesystem was mounted on Linux (Debian). Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: well that was too easy

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              7028736
Filesystem created:       Sat Nov 14 20:49:49 2009
Last mount time:          Wed Jun  9 18:19:42 2010
Last write time:          Thu Jun  3 09:38:18 2010
Mount count:              20
Maximum mount count:      32
```

and `tune2fs` handles ext4 partitions too, I just don't have one handy.

Comment: This works only for ext* and requires root privilege. I'm looking for this answer but for anykind of FS (local, NFS, etc).

Answer (score 7):

I've just found a way for NFS by reading `/proc/self/mountstats` (or any other PID).
It gives the age in seconds:

```
device 1.2.3.4:/HOME mounted on /mnt/HOME with fstype nfs statvers=1.1
[...]
    age:    1047998
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, msw's original "not too easy" answer from the edit history is below:

---

According to `include/linux/ext3_fs.h` the mount time is stored at offset 0x2c in the superblock of an ext3 partition:

```
...
/*
 * Structure of the super block
 */
struct ext3_super_block {
/*00*/  __le32  s_inodes_count;     /* Inodes count */
    __le32  s_blocks_count;     /* Blocks count */
    __le32  s_r_blocks_count;   /* Reserved blocks count */
    __le32  s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
/*10*/  __le32  s_free_inodes_count;    /* Free inodes count */
    __le32  s_first_data_block; /* First Data Block */
    __le32  s_log_block_size;   /* Block size */
    __le32  s_log_frag_size;    /* Fragment size */
/*20*/  __le32  s_blocks_per_group; /* # Blocks per group */
    __le32  s_frags_per_group;  /* # Fragments per group */
    __le32  s_inodes_per_group; /* # Inodes per group */
    __le32  s_mtime;        /*  Mount time  <--------------------------------------  */
/*30*/  __le32  s_wtime;        /* Write time */
...
```

(I've taken the liberty of making the `Mount time` a little easier to find.)