# How to find out the last time an XFS partition was mounted

Tags: linux, mount, xfs

I found the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/152640/finding-out-the-time-a-filesystem-was-last-mounted), but that only works for EXT* filesystems, there's an answer also for NFS (even though the question tagged ext4). However I'm using XFS so neither of the answers works for me.

There was a comment on the accepted answer that it only works for EXT* and it was suggested that one should ask a new question instead of commenting an old. So here's the new question: how do I find out the last time a XFS file system was mounted?

I'm using Ubuntu, but I think it shouldn't differ between distributions.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Ubuntu uses systemD you may be able to check systemD mount points.
Example:

```
systemctl status var-log-audit.mount

<Snip>
Active: active (mounted) since Tue 2016-06-07 02:06:07 IST; 54s ago
Where: /var/log/audit
<Snip>
```

The timestamp should show the last mount, even if not performed with `systemctl start var-log-audit.mount`.

You could also use journalctl to examine the service unit for log history

```
journalctl -xe -U var-log-audit.mount
```